# Can't get AccountId from Opportunity after update trigger

Tags: after-trigger

I'm having an issue I can't explain when trying to access the AccountId field in an Opportunity after update trigger.

Here's the trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityAfter on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    for (String oid : Trigger.newMap.keySet()) {
        Opportunity opp = Trigger.newMap.get(oid);
        System.debug('EPM Log: opp.AccountId: ' + opp.AccountId);
    }
}
```

And here's the test I'm running:

```
@isTest static void testOppWithAccountId() {
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Test Account';
    insert acc;
    
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    opp.Name = 'Test Opp';
    opp.Account = acc;
    opp.StageName = 'Prospecting';
    opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
    insert opp;

    opp.My_Custom_Field__c = Date.today();
    update opp;
}
```

I would expect to get the AccountId in the debug log, but it's coming back null.

Can anyone help me get unstuck here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate the relationship field in your test, not the connected sObject value. So not

```
opp.Account = acc;
```

but

```
opp.AccountId = acc.Id;
```

Updating related sObject instances has no effect when you perform DML.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea that was the case. Amazed I (or anyone on my team) has come across this before. Thanks so much for the quick and sanity-saving response.